# Why isn't this case insensitive version of strstr() function working?

Tags: c, string

In an effort of solving a textbook problem, I'm trying to create a case insensitive version of the function called `strstr()` which is in the C language. So far, I've run into two problems. The first problem being that when I make the case insensitive version of `strstr()` it worked, but it didn't stop at the first matching string and continued to return the string even if they didn't match.

`strstr()` is supposed to see the first instance of a matching character up to n counts specified and then stop. Like if I wrote: `"Xehanort"` in string `A` and `"Xemnas"` in string `B` and specified `4`, as the `number`, it would return `Xe`.

The idea behind the case insensitive version is that I can write : `"Xehanort"` in one string and `"xemnas"` in the next string and have it return `Xe`.

However, I've run into a new problem in new code I've tried: the function doesn't seem to want to run at all. I've tested this and it turns out the function seems to be at a crash and I'm not sure how to make it stop.

I've tried editing the code, I've tried using different for loops but figured that the code doesn't need to be too sophisticated yet, I've also tried different code entirely than what you are going to read, but that resulted in the problem mentioned earlier.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MAX 100

char *stristr4(const char *p1, const char *p2, size_t num);

int main() {
    char c[MAX], d[MAX];
    printf("Please enter the string you want to compare.");
    gets(c);
    printf("Please enter the next string you want to compare.");
    gets(d);
    printf("The first string to be obtained from \n%s, and \n%s is \n%s",
           c, d, stristr4(c, d, MAX));
}

char *stristr4(const char *p1, const char *p2, size_t num) {
    const char *str1 = p1;
    const char *str2 = p2;
    char *str3;
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
            if (tolower(str1[i]) == tolower(str2[j])) {
                str3[i] = str1[i];
                counter++;
            } else {
                if (counter > 0) {
                    break;
                } else
                    continue;
            }
        }
    }
    return str3;
}
```

The code you see will ask for the strings you want to input. Ideally, it should return the input.

Then it should do the `stristr` function and return the first instance of matching string with case insensitivity.

However, the function I've created doesn't even seem to run.

Comment: "*Strstr() is supposed to see the first instance of a matching character up to n counts specified and then stop.*" That's not how `strstr` works.

Comment: You're not making `char *str3;` point to anything, and then you do `str3[i] = str1[i];`. Doesn't your compiler warn you here?

Comment: `strstr` only takes two arguments. `strstr("Xehanort", "Xemnas")` is supposed to return `NULL`.

Comment: @Blaze No, it doesn't.

Comment: @melphomene Okay dude, that's a no. It says right here in my book that it only returns null if it finds no match.

Comment: @Matthew_J_Barnes then see if you can configure it be more strict with warnings. Mine flat-out refuses to compile this.

Comment: Never use `gets`. It has been removed from the C language because it cannot be used safely.

Comment: @Matthew_J_Barnes There is no match for `"Xemnas"` in `"Xehanort"`. What do you think is the purpose of `strstr`?

Comment: @melpomene  'Xe' in Xemnas and 'Xe' in Xehanort don't match in your world. . . .? Also, I'll stop using gets once I finish this book. Thanks, now if we can just move onto my question.

Comment: `strstr` doesn't look for a common prefix; it does a substring search. `"Xemnas"` is not a substring of `"Xenahort"`, so no, there is no match.

Comment: @Matthew_J_Barnes it's a match only if the **entire** word matches, not just two letters of it. From the documentation at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strstr : *"Finds the first occurrence of the byte string target in the byte string pointed to by str."*

Comment: It's the stated behaviour of library function [`strstr()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strstr-wcsstr-mbsstr-mbsstr-l?view=vs-2017) that matters. *Returns a pointer to the first occurrence of `strSearch` in `str`, or `NULL` if `strSearch` does not appear in `str`.*

Comment: @Blaze you're right, thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you for clearing that up. Okay, that makes sense.

Comment: "*now if we can just move onto my question*" - What's the point? It was already answered by Blaze's first comment up there.

Comment: @melpomene Thank you for your help and your time. I realize you are more experienced than me and could have spent your time elsewhere, so I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Blaze I got it to work, but what you said has me concerned. Also, I got a warning from my compiler: initialization discards const qualifier from compiler when making p3 point to p2.

Comment: Edit: Okay, I have a bug. P3 points to P2, but it makes the code that I have irrelevant. Basically, it's going to return P3 as P2 whether or not anything matches.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be making copies of the strings (and certainly shouldn't be modifying them) — but if you do, you must manage the space. Consider that you're searching for a needle in a haystack (something small in something big). You should be returning a pointer to a location in the haystack.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you Johnathan. I think I made a better version of strstr() because rather than JUST looking for a full matching string, it looks for the first instance of matching characters (as I sincerely think strstr() should) so I can compare Xehanort is cool and Xehanort and get Xehanort. I can also compare Xehanort is cool and Xemnas and get Xe.

Comment: @Matthew_J_Barnes *as I sincerely think strstr() should* [`strstr()` has been standardized to look for the entire string for more than thirty years.  Literally.](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#4.11.5.7)

Comment: Serious lack of creativity here. . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A third string could be passed to the function and fill that string with the matching characters.
Use `fgets` instead of `gets`.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 100

int stristr4(const char* p1, const char *p2, char *same);

int main( void)
{
    int comp = 0;
    char c[MAX] = "", d[MAX] = "", match[MAX] = "";//initialize to all zero

    printf ( "Please enter the string you want to compare. ");
    fflush ( stdout);//printf has no newline so make sure it prints
    fgets ( c, MAX, stdin);
    c[strcspn ( c, "\n")] = 0;//remove newline
    printf ( "Please enter the next string you want to compare. ");
    fflush ( stdout);//printf has no newline so make sure it prints
    fgets ( d, MAX, stdin);
    d[strcspn ( d, "\n")] = 0;//remove newline
    comp = stristr4 ( c, d, match);
    printf ( "Comparison of \n%s, and \n%s  is \n%d\n", c, d, comp);
    if ( *match) {
        printf ( "The matching string to be obtained from \n%s, and \n%s is \n%s\n"
        , c, d, match);
    }
    return 0;
}

int stristr4 ( const char *p1,const char *p2, char *same)
{
    //pointers not pointing to zero and tolower values are equal
    while ( *p1 && *p2 && tolower ( (unsigned char)*p1) == tolower ( (unsigned char)*p2))
    {
        *same = tolower ( (unsigned char)*p1);//count same characters
        same++;//increment to next character
        *same = 0;//zero terminate
        p1++;
        p2++;
    }
    return *p1 - *p2;//return difference
}
```

Comment: You should cast `char` values as `(unsigned char)` when passing them to `tolower()` as `tolower()` has undefined behavior for negative values, except for `EOF`. `char` may be signed by default: in this case, `stristr4()` would have undefined behavior on strings with non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has undefined behavior (in this case causing a segmentation fault), because you try to store the resulting string via an uninitialized pointer `str3`.

Standard function `strstr` returns a pointer to the matching subsequence, you should do the same. The third argument is useless if the first and second arguments are proper C strings.

Here is a modified version:

```c
char *stristr4(const char *p1, const char *p2) {
    for (;; p1++) {
        for (size_t i = 0;; i++) {
            if (p2[i] == '\0')
                return (char *)p1;
            if (tolower((unsigned char)p1[i]) != tolower((unsigned char)p2[i]))
                break;
        }
        if (*p1 == '\0')
            return NULL;
    }
}
```

Notes:

- function `tolower()` as other functions from `<ctype.h>` takes an `int` argument that must have the value of an `unsigned char` or the special negative value `EOF`. `char` arguments must be converted to `unsigned char` to avoid undefined behavior for negative `char` values. `char` can be signed or unsigned by default depending on the platform and the compilers settings.
- you should **never** use `gets()`. This function is obsolete and cannot be used safely with uncontrolled input. Use `fgets()` and strip the trailing newline:

  ```
    if (fgets(c, sizeof c, stdin)) {
        c[strcspn(c, "\n")] = '\0';  // strip the trailing newline if any
        ...
    }
  ```